# convert float to int in mixed datatype dictionairy

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

bit stuck on something which is probably easy to solve, but all of the examples I found are talking about uniform key:value pairs.

What I want to achieve is the following :

I have a dictionary containing mixed values (strings and floats), and all the floats should be converted to int, otherwise the string is kept.

example :

```
d = {"key1":"something","key2":200.0, "key3":"another string", "key4":2017.0}
```

should become :

```
{"key1":"something","key2":200, "key3":"another string", "key4":2017}
```

I tried something like this in some variations but no luck

```
d = {k: int(v) if float(v) else v for k, v in d.items()}
```

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if float(v)` does **not check whether `v` is a float**: it only checks if the truthiness of the result of converting `v` to a float is `True`. If `float(v)` raises an exception however, the exception is *not* catched.

You can **use `isinstance(..)`** to check if an object has a certain type:

```
{k: int(v) if isinstance(v, float) else v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Which will produce a dictionary like:

```
>>> {k: int(v) if isinstance(v, float) else v for k, v in d.items()}
{'key2': 200, 'key4': 2017, 'key1': 'something', 'key3': 'another string'}
```